# MySQL: Key field value unique to 2 tables

Tags: mysql

I'm looking to have 3 tables in a MySQL database that control, say items for sale in an online shop. The 3 tables are as follows:

1. Current items
2. Discontinued items
3. Invoicing

I've split the items into 2 tables to prevent the website having to look up the entire current and discontinued items when listing the sale items on the site. The website only needs to list the current items so I think doing this will speed up performance as the site grows. The query to list stock will be run frequently.

Once items are not longer for sale, they will be 'decanted' into the discontinued table and new items will be added to the current items table.

Each invoice will refer to a unique key field of the items databases (current or discontinued) to identify what items were on that invoice.

In order for this to work, when a new item is created and added to the current items table, the key field will need to be unique to both tables. Otherwise, the invoicing will potentially reference 2 items as it looks through both the current and discontinued tables to work out what items were on each invoice.

Is there a way to assign a unique value to a field that is unique to 2 different tables?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Gordon's answer forgot to mention that you should almost never worry about performance while in development. Performance fixes are only done when you have good statistical data showing that your application is running slow. The thing you need to worry about while developing your application is good programming practices and data consistency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a poor design.

Instead, just have a `discontinued` flag in an `items` table -- perhaps along with `DiscontinuedDate`.

This will allow you to maintain referential integrity.  It will simplify queries, because an item reference will always go to one table.

If you like, you can then create two views on the `items` table:  `v_ItemsCurrent` and `v_ItemsDiscontinued`.  These would use a `where` clause to choose the appropriate set of items.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm a bit conscience of scalability. After a couple of rounds of discontinuing items and then adding new stock, the table will start to get quite large. When a user connects to my website the whole table will need to be searched to return a fraction of the total entries. This query will be run almost every time someone visits the site. It seems a waste to have to run this query which is why I was hoping to split the tables.

Comment: @hojkoff . . . What do you consider to be quite large?  MySQL can easily handle tables with millions of rows.  You may have to learn about strategies such as indexing and partitioning to get the performance you want.